# Overriding controls behavior in the Ribbon

Tags: ribbon, editing-menu

Is there any way to override the standard behavior (javascript) of Ribbon controls?
For example, I need the Color selector populate not all the colors available, but a restricted subset of them.
In the CMDUI.xml file I see that `Ribbon.EditingTools.CPEditTab.Font.FontColor` element has an attribute `PopulatequeryCommand="GetFontColorMenuXml"`.
So, is it any way to override this out-of-the-box Command, so that it returns specified colors instead of standard set, or I need to develop my own color picker and replace the standard with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that this can be done without changing OOTB javascript and definition files. This is not recommended.

So, yes - you need to develop your own color picker, hide default one and show custom in same place.

I also found this article:

- [How to create a custom color picker flyout in the SharePoint ribbon](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/weslbo/archive/2011/04/21/how-to-create-a-custom-color-picker-flyout-in-the-sharepoint-ribbon.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

In short, you can customize it. Here is a nice example:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/weslbo/archive/2011/04/21/how-to-create-a-custom-color-picker-flyout-in-the-sharepoint-ribbon.aspx

Comment: Skog, you're always welcome :)